# Why my oracle BKP script keeps going to $ORACLE_HOME\dbs

Tags: oracle, rman

I have this script to make a lvl0 BKP of my Oracle database. Also I'm forcing to allocate in a directory it keeps going to the $ORACLE_HOME\dbs and not to the one I pointed in the configuration disk parameters:

```
allocate channel d1 device type disk format '/backup/Rman/LIFE/FULL/%U.bkp';
crosscheck archivelog from time 'sysdate -1';
crosscheck archivelog all;
crosscheck backup of database;
backup incremental level 0 noexclude check logical tag Historico filesperset 15 keep until time 'sysdate+180' logs database format 'db_L0_%d_%s_%p_%T_%U.rman';
backup current controlfile tag Historico keep until time 'sysdate+180' logs format 'Ctl_%d_%s_%p_%T_%U.rman';
backup spfile tag Historico keep until time 'sysdate+180' logs format 'Spfile_%d_%s_%p_%T_%U.rman';
release channel d1;
}
list backup of archivelog  from  time 'sysdate-4';
list backup of database summary completed after 'sysdate -5';


thanks!
```

Comment: I run you command in run block in my environment, they run successful and put backup in  /backup/Rman/LIFE/FULL/ , I am guess there is permission problem of  /backup/Rman/LIFE/FULL/ in your environment.

Comment: you sure its not just your control file autobackup? Thats the most common thing we see dumped into $OH/dbs

Comment: keeps going to $OH  piece handle=/oracle/TIME/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_2/dbs/db_L0_LIFE_19792_1_20201117_agvfo1mq_1_1.rman tag=BKP_LVL0 comment=NONE
channel d1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:03:25
channel d1: starting incremental level 0 datafile backup set
channel d1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set

Comment: i know now where the problem its, its in the line 'db_L0_%d_%s_%p_%T_%U.rman';